# CNTK: The number (1) of sequence start flags does not match the number (356) of sequences

Tags: python, deep-learning, sequence, lstm, cntk

Getting the error:

> ValueError: Value::Create:: The number (1) of sequence start flags does not match the number (356) of sequences,
>   In

```
def create_inputs(output_length):
    batch_axis = ct.Axis.default_batch_axis()
    input_seq_axis = ct.Axis('inputAxis')

    input_dynamic_axes = [batch_axis, input_seq_axis]
    input_sequence = ct.input_variable(shape=1, dynamic_axes=input_dynamic_axes)
    label_sequence = ct.input_variable(shape=output_length, dynamic_axes=input_dynamic_axes)

    return input_sequence, label_sequence

def make_model_and_train(model_root_path, epochs, minibatch_dim, output_length, test_minibatches):
    vals = get_data('data.csv')
    train, test, minibatches_per_epoch = make_sets(vals, minibatch_dim, output_length, test_minibatches)

    input_sequence, label_sequence = create_inputs(output_length)

    model = create_model(output_length)

    z = model(input_sequence)

    ce = ct.squared_error(z, label_sequence) 

    lt_per_sample = ct.learning_rate_schedule([(7000, 0.001),(10000, 0.0005)], ct.UnitType.sample, minibatches_per_epoch)
    clipping_threshold_per_sample = 2
    gradient_clipping_with_truncation = True

    learner = ct.momentum_sgd(z.parameters, lt_per_sample, ct.momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(1100),gradient_clipping_threshold_per_sample = clipping_threshold_per_sample, gradient_clipping_with_truncation = gradient_clipping_with_truncation)
    progress_printer = ct.logging.ProgressPrinter(100, tag = 'Training')
    trainer = ct.Trainer(z, (ce), learner, progress_printer)

    print ("Running %d epochs with %d minibatches per epoch" % (epochs, minibatches_per_epoch))
    print('')

    for e in range(epochs):
        mask = [True]
        for b in range(minibatches_per_epoch):
            arguments = ({input_sequence: train[0][b], label_sequence: train[1][b]}, mask)
            mask = [False]
            trainer.train_minibatch(arguments)

            global_minibatch = e*minibatches_per_epoch + b
        if e % 100 == 0 and e != 0:
            model_filename = '%s/%s/%s_epoch_%g.dnn' % (model_root_path, name, name, e+1)
            z.save_model(model_filename)
            print("Saved model to '%s'" % model_filename)
```

At

```
trainer.train_minibatch(arguments)
```

minibatch_dim is 356,
output_length is 356

I mostly copied the code from my other LSTM, which worked, but I keep getting this error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a list of mask values, for each sequence in the minibatch, with the i-th element in the list being True if the i-th sequence is new sequence or if it is a continuation of the i-th sequence from the previous minibatch

Comment: But how do I do that? Can you please provide an example or change some of my code? Sorry, the CNTK documentation is lacking.